# simple_html_dom получить содержимое первого тега

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Почему к первому тегу залипает второй тег  `textarea`
когда явно указываю на первый.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://домен.com?num_iid=538522618444');
print_r($html->find('textarea[ondblclick]',0)->plaintext);
```

Но при этом когда меняю индекс на `1` получаю содержимое второго тега `textarea[ondblclick]` без лишних тегов чистый массив

Comment: да вроде json возвращает ведь. а второй это принт массива, который возвращается при 1.

Comment: @teran выдача json есть только не чистый, к нему залипает и принт массива, при индексе `0`

Comment: да, действительно

Comment: @teran в этом и вся проблема =)

Comment: которую не мешало бы озвучить в вопросе, да? :) вообще потенциально должен быть вариант получить просто выдачу в json, зачем еще эта страница то, не понятно. Возможно библиотека не корректно работает, потому что там лишний тэг `</fieldset>` есть. и может быть проще вообще строковыми/регулярками обрезать нужное.

Comment: @teran исправил вопрос, в бесплатном варианте не как не получить только json, лишний тег ведь не внутри тега `textarea` регулярками конечно можно но как по мне так не красиво.

Comment: в общем это похоже на баг библиотеки, либо невалидность разметки. на вашем месте я бы просто обрезал контент по начальному и конечному тэгу и все. Это все равно гораздо эффективней по производительности, чем грузить и парсить DOM и в нем искать. Так что для этой задачи нет особого смысла использовать dom-парсер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да действительно так проще:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('http://домен.com?num_iid=538522618444');
if (preg_match('%<textarea.*?>(.*?)</textarea%is', $txt, $mm) ){
//      print_r($mm[1]);
        $aa = json_decode($mm[1], true);
        print_r($aa);
}
```